# Laptop unable to connect to the router

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a D-Link DIR-655 router, which is working fine for all the phones in the house, as well as one laptop and a desktop. I factory reset one of my laptops because it was getting slow and filled with programs I don't use anymore. After I did this I'm not able to connect to the router anymore and use wireless. A wired connection works fine, but whenever I try to connect to the wireless network I get the error "Windows was unable to connect to __". When I trouble shoot it tells me to turn off the router, laptop and re-try which I already have and then goes on to tell me that there's a problem with my wireless adapter or access point.

I've gone through device manager and everything is working properly so I can only think of the problem being with the router. MAC filtering is turned off, I turned it on and allowed the laptop to access the network and that didn't work. I enabled a guest zone for the wifi and this DID work in allowing my laptop connection to the network.

Does anyone have any suggestions other that resetting my router?

Comment: If the problem appears only with the laptop you have reseted and not with others devices like desktop pc or phones i will concentrate on a laptop issue but not on a router issue. Are you sure about your wifi setup on laptop, mean security (WPA, WPA2 etc...) and key ? Maybe Wifi adapter driver ?

Comment: The key is correct, adapter drivers are up to date. I've had this problem before where the security on the router doesn't let devices connect if they're new.

Comment: ok. Depends on your router, maybe you have an ARP cache that you can clear.

Comment: Have you tried power-cycling the router?  I've seen issues like this before with D-link routers, after a few weeks of uptime they start getting flakey.

Comment: I'm power cycled it a few times, it doesn't seem to fix the problem. I've cleared the ARP cache just now, didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: It may be a hassle but your next step is to factory reset the router if you're convinced it's not the laptop.

Comment: It was a problem with the router, I factory reset it and the laptop works perfectly fine now. Thanks everyone for trying to help!

Comment: i was in the same situation . uninstall wifi driver (force delete driver) and then install original laptop driver from its site, restart and tell the result